# What happened to Wolverine from the new Days of Future past time line?

Tags: marvel, x-men, wolverine, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past

At the end of *X-Men: Days of Future Past*, we see Wolverine

> wake up in a new timeline.

After a few “surprises”,

> he sees Professor X, and Professor X senses that this Wolverine is not the Wolverine from his timeline.

What happened to the Wolverine in this timeline?

Answer (score 2):

Presumably he got overwritten by the Wolverine from the other timeline, just like everyone else who went to the past and came back. For most of them it was just minutes, not enough to make them a different person, but in his case it was decades.

It is disturbing but similar things have happened in other films.